# Lead: Do not want to send email to Lead Email , just to email address mentioned in toAddresses of Messaging.SingleEmailMessage, using Trigger

Tags: apex, email

Requirement : Lead has field named Email. Whenever you use TemplateId and targetobjectId in SingleEmailMessage object, an email always gets delivered to Lead Email. Now as per requirement we don't want to send Email to this lead's email address and only to addresses mentioned in setToAddresses in trigger/class.

note: We are using templateId and TargetObjectId as it is necessary to use.

Kindly  help me.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this blog, this may help : http://www.forcetree.com/2009/07/sending-email-from-your-apex-class.html. But it does not mention about using templateId and TargetObjectId in conjuction with setToaddresses. Have you tried it so far ?

Comment: Yes I am using all 3 at once i.e. templateId , TargetObjectId and setToaddresses. Mail is getting delivered to Lead Email add. and also to setToAddresses email addresses.  I also visited the link you provided but it is not resolving my problem.